# Reading sub-directories of a directory in class path resources with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jar, directory

I was trying to read sub-directories(names of directories) of a directory in my class path resources using Spring Boot with snippet given below.

```
    public List<File> getSubdirectories() {
    File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:/database/scripts");
    return Arrays.stream(file.listFiles()).filter(File::isDirectory).map(File::getFileName)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Now this would work well when we run this code from IDE.
But when we build this app as a jar and runs it from there it throws a **FileNotFoundException**.

I tried to load the directory as class path resource as well. But didn't find any luck.

I'm currently using Java 8. So most of the Java 7 solutions won't work I guess.
Is there any other way I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

As per Spring [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/ResourceUtils.html) ResourceUtils are to be used internally within the framework

Try using Resource instead:

```
@Value("classpath:database/scripts")
Resource directories;
```

Alternatively, you can use resource loader:

```
@Autowired
ResourceLoader resourceLoader;
...
public Resource loadDirectories() {
    return resourceLoader.getResource(
      "classpath:database/scripts");
}
```

Comment: This won't work well as I need child directory names of the parent directory.

Comment: Why not? Resource has getFile() method. You can check later if that file is directory and list everything like this
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        search(".*\\.java", directories.getFile(), result);

Comment: I just realized you wrote the parent directory. Why not then just get the resource 'database'?

Comment: We can do this while we use an IDE. But from a JAR file this will fail. It will throw a file not found exception.

Comment: Have you checked if your directories actually exist inside your jar?

Comment: Yes. Directories exist in JAR. But the path to the directory is not getting resolved.  I think it's some issue with Java 8 and File api.